# Apache and Manual executions of the same shell script produces different results

Tags: bash, apache

When executing my shell script from apache (running inside docker with ubuntu + apache + mtools (mongodb mtools) I get the following result:

```
...
Executing mlogvis --no-browser filename
<br>
<br>
<br>

usage: mlogvis [-h] [--version] [--no-progressbar] [--no-browser] [--out OUT] [--line-max LINE_MAX] mlogvis: error: unrecognized arguments: filename 
...
```

But if I connect to my docker container, switch to `www-data` and run `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.sh` I get the following (This is the expected output):

```
...
Executing mlogvis --no-browser filename
<br>
<br>
<br>

copying /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/data/index.html to /tmp/filename.html
...
```

As you can see when I run the script through hitting the apache endpoint the `mtools` command does not work as expected. The exact same script runs fine if I manually run it as `www-data`

Here is the script, redacted true values (as they are trivial):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<title>Some Title</title>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'

ENV="env"
METHOD="mlogvis"

BUCKET="MY_BUCKET"
BUCKET_PREFIX="${ENV}/${NODE}"
FILE_NAME="filename"
echo "<br>"

echo "Attempting to download find and process: ${FILE_NAME}.gz in bucket: ${BUCKET}/$BUCKET_PREFIX"
echo "<br>"

rm -rf /tmp/s3 || true  && mkdir /tmp/s3

cd /tmp/s3

s3cmd -c /etc/s3cmd/.s3cfg get --server-side-encryption -e "s3://${BUCKET}/${BUCKET_PREFIX}/${FILE_NAME}.gz"  2>&1

echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"

echo "Gunzipping ${FILE_NAME}.gz" 2>&1
gunzip -v ${FILE_NAME}.gz 2>&1
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"

ls -lah
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"

head -n10 "$FILE_NAME" 2>&1
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"

echo "Executing $METHOD --no-browser $FILE_NAME" 2>&1
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"

"$METHOD" --no-browser "$FILE_NAME" 2>&1
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"
echo "<br>"

ls -lah

echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
exit 0
```

Edit: for clarity once inside my running container this is how I switched to the `www-data` user:

```
su -s /bin/bash www-data
```